# Use Windows Service "Log on as" user as NetworkCredentials for a web request

Tags: c#, windows-services, networkcredentials

I developped a windows service that is running Logged On as: a specific windows user. 
I use this user, because it has permission for  web site I need to request in this windows service.

The issue is that when requesting the web, using CredentialsCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials i uses the credentials of the current user logged in(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()) to windows which has no access to this web. I

I need in some way to pass the Credentials of the Windows service's "Log In as" user:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("some url");
// the user running the service can be get from here:
// WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(), but not the password
request.Credentials = "some code tobtain the user from the service user"
```

If I use:

```
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

it uses the user from the windows account NOT the windows service account.

Any ideas?

Comment: For Network credentials to work the user need to be in the same Window user Group on both local PC and Remote PC.  If you are in a corporate network then talk to your MIS about the Group Policy.

Answer (score 0):

> the user running the service can be get from here: WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(), but not the password

If you can get the current `WindowsIdentity`, you should be able to [impersonate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.7.2) it:

```
WindowsIdentity currentIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = currentIdentity.Impersonate())
{
    // Check the identity.
    Console.WriteLine("After impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
    // Make the request
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://google.com");
    // etc
}
```